# CI cart session works properly with FF,Chrome,Safari but fails in IE

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

Building pizza delivery site. 
Currently using:
Language: PHP
Framework: codeigniter
class: Cart Class

Autoloaded: session

Products can be easily added into the cart in FF,safari,chrome. but does not seem to be working in Internet Explorer.

Tried all solutions posted on the codeigniter forums but nothing works.

Comment: Under no circumstances add more detailed info about the problem. It would take all the suspense away! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tried all solutions posted on the codeigniter forums but nothing works

Sadly I haven't got a couple weeks to trawl through "all solutions posted on codeigniter forums" and even then it would be a waste of time since any worthwhile answer to the problem would describe how to diagnose the specific problem, not just how to fix it; I have access to your systems to run diagnostics myself.

Get hold of [iehttpheaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders.html) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and check what's happening to the session cookies.

And do make some time to read [this article](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

C.

Answer (score 0):

I did only one config change that I just saw in another post in StackOverFlow and it totally worked for me.

You need to change your config file
from this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

to:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
```

and that's it, hope it helps!